# Get list of Google Business Reviews for any business?

Tags: google-my-business-api

Can I get a list of reviews from an arbitrary business?

[It appears](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews) like you get a list of the reviews for a specific account and location.

`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/accounts/account_name/locations/location_name/reviews`

However, you can only get a list of account for an authenticated user.

`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/accounts`

Is there an endpoint or way to list out the reviews for any business? I just need the number or reviews, and really don't want to have to look at screen scraping type solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The Places API returns only 5 for a business, GMB API requires the user as you’ve mentioned to authenticate; there’s no official endpoint for getting all listed reviews unless you either scrape the data; like Yelp, Google didn’t make it available to pull all user contributed content such as reviews; alternatively you can create your own DB for some businesses and manually update by pulling reviews off a third party site (eg: ReviewsMaker.com) where you can copy data to a table and keep track, but there’s no other real-time solution other than using the GMB API (which is restricted only to authenticated users)